# How to Show a link in footer when site is in mobile version?

Tags: magento

I want to show a link in footer to view desktop site. my mobile site url and desktop site url is different.I only want this link in mobile site so that if a user want to show full desktop site so he/she can click on link which is in footer and can see full version of the site. i want to put it in a condition i.e., only in mobile version not in desktop version. i want this without using manage store. if anyone knows this, then please help me out. thanks!

I have added a Magento Mobile HTML5 Theme in admin now howcan i add a link in footer, i am not getting it...please explain briefly

Comment: means I have to put one mobile theme extension in my site? please explain it.I am not getting this

Comment: Please see above and tell me how to get mobile theme in front end so that i will go to footer.phtml

Comment: accept the answer if its useful to you

Answer (score 0):

In your Magento Mobile HTML5 Theme, locate **footer.phtml** and place a link for 'View Desktop Site' and redirect it to your main store theme.